# Can't sign in with corporate account when acquiring authentication token with PublicClientApplication

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-ad-msal

I have a custom UWP application which I have registered in portal.azure.com. The app has been configured to support all account types ("Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)").

In my application I create a IPublicClientApplication like so:

```
PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                    .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount)
                    .WithLogging((level, message, containsPii) =>
                    {
                        ConfigurationHandler.Log.Info($"MSAL: {level} {message} ");
                    }, LogLevel.Warning, enablePiiLogging: false, enableDefaultPlatformLogging: true)
                    .WithUseCorporateNetwork(true)
                    .Build();
```

And later on I'm trying to acquire an authentication token like so:

```
authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                                                  .ExecuteAsync()
                                                  .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will open the sign in popup window where user enters their email address and password. The authentication works without issues when I'm using a personal (xyz@outlook.com) account but it doesn't work with work accounts. The window is trying to redirect to the organization sign in page after entering the work email and clicking next. The redirect process begins but always ends up to following error:

> "We can't connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this again later"

I have tried to add WithRedirectUri with value "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" to the PublicClientApplication creation but it didn't help. That's the only redirect URI I have configured in Azure Portal.

Is there some other setting which I'm not aware of? How can I get rid of this error and get the work accounts working as well?

EDIT: I forgot to mention it's a desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adding a missing certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities in Windows certificate manager.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your issue on my side. My steps seem the same as yours, anyway, here is the screenshot for your reference. Also, here is an complete [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-uwp#enable-integrated-authentication-on-federated-domains-optional).

[image]

By the way, if you want to integrate authentication on federated domains, you need to enale additional capabilities.

1.Open `Package.appxmanifest`.

2.Select **Capabilities** and enable the following settings:

- **Enterprise Authentication**
- **Private Networks (Client & Server)**
- **Shared User Certificates**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I triple checked that I have same configurations on the Portal and capabilities include everything you listed. Here's a strange thing though: I tried to reproduce the problem on my laptop but it doesn't happen on it. Could this problem be related to Windows configuration somehow? I have mainly developed the software on my desktop and the problem with the company account happens only on it. It's connected to the company network via ethernet cable. The laptop is also on the same network but it's using wifi. Are there some settings to check on the OS level?